# send individual invite with dialog for Native iOS app via Facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-invite, facebook-messenger

I want to send individual invite to friends from my Native iOS app, through Facebook. It should contain Link and pre-filled invite message..Is it possible? What is the better approach. I referred `FBAppInvite`  and `FBSDKMessageDialog`  tutorial on https://developers.facebook.com/ , could not find anything which fulfils my requirement.

Can any one suggest some approach how to implement this?. I have not worked much on using social frameworks. Facebook implementation steps are not clear. I searched for demo or sample project on this, but could not find clear documents. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Messenger with dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147608/facebook-messenger-with-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for invitation read following link..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios

Comment: hi, I referred that..but How to get App link in that..every time it is showing invalid app link. I used exiting app link from play store.

Comment: you must be create applinking in facebook

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/866112753470134/?platform=app-links-host using this link

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you tell me why my friends are not getting notified or no getting any message for app invite?

Comment: If a previewImageURL is not set the invite will use Promotional Images from the App Details section in apps settings. The invite will not show if no images are available.

Comment: I have added preview image. But still it is not showing invite.

Comment: FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/randomnumbers"];
//    content.previewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ec2-107-21-15-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/static/event_placeholder.jpg"];
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ec2-107-21-15-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/static/event_placeholder.jpg"];
    
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                                 delegate:self];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93354/discussion-between-maulik-and-user3575114).

Comment: @Maulik, i can send invites to my friends but they are not getting notified and i m getting the result as nil in  "appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults:" delegate method can u please help out this